# Increase ulimit nproc for user other than root in docker container

Tags: docker, kernel, docker-container, ulimit

I want to increase ulimit for a docker container. I changed the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file, added `ulimit -n 65000` and was able to increase the ulimit for docker **root** user only. The same property is not inherited for any other users inside the docker container.

Any clues, why does this happen? How can I increase ulimit for another user other than root inside docker container? Can anybody help?